# TypeError: Service.functionName is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, service

I have service something like this

```
angular.module('services').factory('DownloadService',[$resource,
  function($resource){
    return $resource('path/to/service/download', {}, {
      downloadFile: {
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'path/to/service/download?fileID=:fileID'
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Then in controller i have function where i call this service and call that function on click on file

```
    angular.module('search').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','DownloadService',
      function ($scope,DownloadService){

        $scope.downloadDocument = function(id){
           DownloadService.downloadFile({
            fileId: id
           });
        };
}])
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError:DownloadService.downloadFile is not a function...
```

Comment: Try to add module name to angular.module()

Comment: I have, i edited it is not that, why it is not recognizing as function i have no idea....

Comment: You have wrong syntax in your factory .factory('DownloadService',[$resource,

Comment: How do you mean? I have used service with this syntax and it was working...

Comment: It shoud be .factory('DownloadService', ['$resource', function($resource) {

Comment: change and not working agian...

Comment: I am really confused why it says that it is not a function when obviously it is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have `services` module specified as a dependency when you created the `search` module, i.e. something like

```
angular.module('search', ['services', ...])
```

Further, ensure that you do NOT have a different service within `search` or any of the other modules it depends on with the name `DownloadService`.

---

You might just want to add an `alert` or `console.log` in the services' DownloadService to make sure it is being instantiated.

Or better still, just rename it to something unique (say `myDownloadService`) in both places.

A `console.log(new DownloadService())` and examining the object for `$downloadFile` is also another way to make sure that angular is injecting the right service.

Comment: you mean to add console.log(new DownloadService()) in function $scope.downloadDocument or in service in downloadFile?

Comment: I would first try renaming it to myDownloadService in both places.

Comment: i am changing now to Seach.DownloadService will see if that is working

Comment: you might want to make it `SeachDownloadService` (without the .) in both the definition and the injection. I'm not sure if angular has any grudges against . in service name :-)

Comment: You are right it was messing with some other name DownloadService. I change it to Search.DownloadService and it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

do**nw**loadFile

and

DownloadService.download**FI**le

Comment: Hey man i edited, i was writing this from other PC not copy/paste it is not typo